# Angular data not showing

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am trying to use the $http service GET method from a site to populate fields. Below is my method for calling the API and inserting the data. Also note that because of conflicts with Laravel, I have substituted `{{}}` with `<%%>`. When I tested the `$scopes` without the API call and everything worked fine, so I am pretty sure that has nothing to do with.

```
var app = angular.module('metaDashboard', []);

/**Changes {{variable}} to <%variable%> for Laravel implementation
*/
app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

/**This is for the meta-dashboard home page and sets the correct number of the below variables.
*/
app.controller('TotalNumberController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/userCount')
      .then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.clientCount = response.data["client"];
        $scope.campaignCount = response.data["campaign"];
        $scope.accountCount = response.data["accounts"];
        $scope.userCount = response.data["user"];
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.clientCount = "N/A";
        $scope.campaignCount = "N/A";
        $scope.accountCount = "N/A";
        $scope.userCount = "N/A";
    });
   }
]);
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? How do you check that this code works as expected?

Comment: Not enough shown for us to help. No indication given if request succeeds, no view template shown and we have no idea what data structure is. Also no mention if any errors thrown or not

Comment: Aditionally to answering @JBNizet's questions, I'd suggest you `console.log` the `response` variable

Comment: First of all you should check the server response - does it actually return valid JSON or some error is happening. Second, take a look at the response itself with something like `console.log(response)` and check that `data` and all its values are there.